# I want to take an id from database and add increment it and generate a new id when a button is clicked and show it in the a input feild

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I want to generate an id when the generate ID button is clicked. When the button is clicked I want to retrieve the maximum id from the database and split it to 2 strings to separate the integer part(The id seems like SFABCD123456). then I want increment integer part by one and concatenate the 2 strings again. Then I want to display it in the empid text input. I want all this to happen without page loading. **In my code when I press the generate id button nothing happens**.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<?php 
//database connection
include 'includes/dbh.php'
?>

<body>

    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">

        <label>ID :</label>
        <input type="text" name="empid" id="empid">
        <button type="submit" id="generateID">GENERATE ID</button>


        <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

</body>
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $id = $_POST['empid'];


    ?>

    <p>
        Name : "<?php echo $name ?>;"
        <br>
        ID: "<?php echo $id ?>;"
    </p>

<?php

    }

?>


<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#generateID").click(function(){
            $.post("generateid.php",function(){
                $("#empid").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

generateid.php

```
<?php


//database connection
include 'includes/dbh.php'


  if(isset($_POST['generateID']))
        {

            $query = "SELECT max(staffID) FROM staff";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
             {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $empid = $row['staffID'];
                }
            }


            $part1 = substr($empid, 0, 6);
            $part2 = intval(substr($empid, 6))+1;
            $part2 = str_pad($part2, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $newstaffID = $part1.$part2;


            echo $newstaffID;

        }
```

Comment: id field in table is `integer` OR `varchar` ?

Comment: you have two `submit` button one `form` its not proper way

Comment: @BhargavChudasama its in varchar

Comment: Hi @vio I'm not an expert on php but I think there are a couple of issues you can consider fixing if you want to increase the chance of getting an answer to your question. First off try to see if you can "break" your example, that is try to see if you can add code that will lure out any error messages and post them here. Once you have an actual error message you can update your title and add the error message in the description. It is difficult for contributors to provide answers to questions that do not have any error message other than "nothing happens". Happy editing :-)

Comment: you're not passing any data using your ajax call

Comment: @StigPerez How could i state an error when there is no error... it just nothing happens when i click the generate id button...it make me annoying...Anyway thanks for the adivice...will be helpful in future questionings

Comment: @vio you could try out a couple of things: verify that `mysqli_num_rows($result)` indeed returns rows, verify that `$row` contains a column named "staffID", verify that each `$part` contains what you expect. The quickest way is to simply echo each verification in a variable, like you do with `$newstaffID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this step

use `type=button` instead of `type=submit`

```
<button type="button" id="generateID">GENERATE ID</button>
```

use jquery ajax code like below

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#generateID").click(function(){
            var id = $('#empid').val();
            $.post("generateid.php",{generateID:id},function(data){
                $("#empid").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

pass `generated id` textbox value to `generateid.php` page and get data back in `function(data)`

add semicolon in `generateid.php`

```
include 'includes/dbh.php'; // add semicolon hehe
```

Comment: what was the issue now? @vio

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ,
when load your index.php, call init function ,
init function has query to get max staff id.  this way you do not need to call ajax request.  when your index.php load init function return max staff id. store it in the php variable.

```
<?php 
function init(){
$query = "SELECT max(staffID) FROM staff";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
             {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $maxstaff_id = $row['staffID'];
                }
            }
}
?>
on generate button click, store php variable value in to javascript variable . var maxstaff_id ="<?php echo $maxstaff_id; ?>";  you can use substr method to get integere portion and you can increment it by 1.   

example : 

var maxstaff_id='php echo $maxstaff_id ?>';   
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#generateID").click(function(){
                var maxstaff_id = maxstaff_id.substr(6);
                maxstaff_id=parseInt(maxstaff_id)+1;
                $("#empid").val(maxstaff_id);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "generateid.php", success: function(result){
            $("#empid").val(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="name">

<label>ID :</label>
<input type="text" name="empid" id="empid">

<button>Generate Id</button>
</body>
</html>
```

generateid.php

```
$sql = "SELECT max(staffID) as max FROM staff";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $eid= $row['max'];
        $eid = substr($eid,6) + 1;
        $neweid = "SFABCD" . $eid;
        echo $neweid;
```

I hope it works for you.